# Bad Access - iPhone Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm a beginner with Xcode and Objective-C, i want to make a view controller in code without a nib file and shape it how i want. Currently with this very simple code I can't seem to even change the background color because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I read on internet it is something with memory management but I can't seem to find the fix for this. Pieces of my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DefaultViewController.h"

@class DefaultViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *rootViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize rootViewController = _rootViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
    self.rootViewController = rvc;
    [rvc release];

    [self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_rootViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The view controller I made via, right click -> new file and UIViewController subclass without xib! In the loadView I only try this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I think you need to show us the code for you DefaultViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that the `rootViewController` doesn't have an initialized view. Hard to tell, since you don't show the code of the `DefaultViewController`. It could also be another error in `DefaultViewController`.

---

FWIW, you have two obsolete ivars:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *rootViewController;
}
```

You can delete these, since you synthesize `_window` and `_rootViewController` and never use the above.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. But first the key problem you are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS is because you are calling self.view.backgroundColor inside the loadView. If you override loadView, you must construct your view hierarchy inside the method. By not creating a view hierarchy in that method you are calling backgroundColor on a view that does not exist. Instead completely remove the loadView method or comment it out and move self.view.backgroundColor into the viewDidLoad method. (Remember even an empty loadView method will be a problem, you need to remove it or comment it out)

Second.. change your code to

```
self.rootViewController = rvc; to self.window.rootViewController = rvc;
```

BTW, once you add a view controller you don't need to add the view of the rootViewController as a subview to the window again. Assigning a view controller to the rootViewController property installs the view controller's view as the content view of the window.

Third. When you are initializing DefaultViewController you do

```
UIViewController *rvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
```

dont do that, instead do

```
DefaultViewController *rvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: I thought this function gets called after the view is actually created, I guess because of the comment above it! Thank you and others too!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code so it's

```
self.window.rootViewController = rvc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

What's inside your `DefaultViewController`? If you are not using a nib file, did you implement `-(void)loadView` ?

Answer (score -1):

<del>You should call:

     UIViewController *rvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"yournib" bundle:nil];

 to load the NIB view. Otherwise, your rvc.view will be nil.</del>

Sorry, I overlooked.

The answer is: you should not call `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` within `- (void)loadView` since `self.view` is `nil` firstly at this stage. He has to show that he has correctly created at least `self.view = [[UIView alloc] init]` in `loadView`.

Comment: The question specifically says that nibs are not being used.